# How to take data from a view and send it to a controller action? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view where I displayed all the records from `Requests` table. Every record has a save and remove button, so the user can add or remove a request to/from `ReqHistory` table.

How can I get the data (ID, Title, Description .etc) of each record, from the request view, and pass it to my add/remove actions in `ReqHistoryController`?

When I submit the form, it won't take the data of the record from the view.

Can anybody help me?

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.Request>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <form asp-action="AddReqToHistory" asp-controller="ReqHistory">
        <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 30rem;">

            <div class="card-header">
                @item.Title
            </div>

            <div class="card-body text-dark">

                <img class="imageThumbnail" src="~/images/@item.ImagePath" asp-append-version="true" alt="image" />

                <p class="card-text">
                    <br />
                    @item.Description
                </p>

                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID" >
                    Details
                </a>

                <input  asp-action="AddReqToHistory" asp-controller="ReqHistory" type="submit" value="Save"  />
                <input asp-action="EliminateReqFromHistory" asp-controller="ReqHistory" type="submit" value="Eliminate"  />

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Here are the two actions from `ReqHistoryController`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddReqToHistory([Bind("ID, Title,Description,ImagePath")] Request model)
{
    var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(currentUser);

    var newReqHistory = new ReqHistory()
        {
                UserId = userId,
                RequestId = model.ID,
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                CategoryID = model.CategoryID,
                PersonID = model.PersonID,
                ImagePath = model.ImagePath
        };

    _context.Add(newReqHistory);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Requests");
}

// POST
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EliminateReqFromHistory(int requestId)
{
    var reqHistory = await _context.ReqHistory.FindAsync(_userManager.GetUserId(User), requestId); //ReqHistory has a composite PK
    _context.ReqHistory.Remove(reqHistory);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Requests");
}
```

`ReqHistory` model class:

```
public class ReqHistory
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }  //1-M relationship

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    //one-to-one relationship
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; } //FK
    public Person Person { get; set; } //nav property
}
```

Here is the `ReqHistory` view:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.ReqHistory>

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">

        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
            </th>
         ...........................
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.RequestId
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.UserId
                </td>
                ..................
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
```

Comment: This is just basic HTML 101. You either need one or more HTML forms with hidden inputs for that data or you need to use AJAX to make the request and dynamically build the post body by selecting the data from the page. In either case, the point is that you must actually provide the data in a means where it can be sent. Random data on the page isn't just automatically sent. That would make no sense.

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but I'm a beginner and I'm still learning. Thank you for your answer! Have a nice day!

Comment: Understood. My point is that you need to learn the basics of things like HTML and JavaScript. You can't just jump into a web application when you don't know how basic web technologies work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <a asp-action="AddReqToHistory" asp-controller="ReqHistory" type="submit" value="Save" asp-route-HEREID="@model.ID" />
        <a asp-action="EliminateReqFromHistory" asp-controller="ReqHistory" type="submit" value="Eliminate" asp-route-HEREID="@model.ID" />
```

you can pass id through asp-route by url method.